# Kendo UI MVC Grid, Custom server binding, specifying unique Sort key on multiple ClientTemplate columns using same bound column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo UI MVC Grid, Custom Server Binding, and have multiple columns based on the same bound data field.  The data field is an array and I am using the ClientTemplate to calculate/display an aggregated value from the array elements and displaying in the grid.  Problem is that when you click on the column to sort, that I get the same bound data name in the server side ajax event for each of the columns.  I am not able to tell which specific column the user is wanting to sort by. 
e.g.

```
public class MyData
{
  public MyArrayData[] Values;
}

.Grid<MyData>()
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Columns(columns => 
    columns.Bound(t => t.Values)
       .Title("Col1")
       .ClientTemplate("JS code to aggregate values for col 1")
   columns.Bound(t => t.Values)
       .Title("Col2")
       .ClientTemplate("JS code to aggregate values for col 2")
```

If you click on Col1 or Col2,  I get "Values" in the Ajax event, I cannot tell which column the user is actually wanting to sort by.

Comment: Seems a bit strange to me to have two columns bound to the same data field. What are you trying to achieve? Could you not just duplicate the values property and have a separate (albeit identical) dataset for each column?

Comment: The data column is an array of other structured values.  The two columns I am displaying are an aggregation of different values in the array.  It is an entity coming directly from Mongo DB. I am trying to use the entity directly without having to project it to a nearly duplicate object, but I am thinking that I will probably have to do this.

Comment: I can't think of a simple way. Pragmatically, I think projecting it would be the least stress.